# t-tests for every element in a matrix using the t-distribution

Tags: r, matrix, statistics

I have three matrices. The sample, the sub-sample and the standard errors of the sub-sample. I would like to test the significance of every element in the sub-sample against their corresponding elements in the sample. The formula to get the t-statistic is the difference between corresponding entries in the sub-sample and the total sample transition probabilities divided by standard errors of the sub-sample. The paper doesn't mention how many degrees of freedom to use. How can I get the test results (significant or not significant) for every element in the matrix form?

paper (pg 210):
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/996d/4574510331fba55553549c2cc9a76f317dac.pdf

The sample:

```
                          Aaa         Aa          A        Baa          Ba          B         Caa
               Aaa 0.34513274 0.38053097 0.21238938 0.05309735 0.008849558 0.00000000 0.000000000
               Aa  0.07563025 0.49747899 0.23193277 0.12268908 0.055462185 0.01680672 0.000000000
               A   0.02335766 0.23357664 0.41313869 0.23065693 0.077372263 0.01751825 0.004379562
               Baa 0.01541096 0.11986301 0.28595890 0.30993151 0.188356164 0.06849315 0.011986301
               Ba  0.00000000 0.08010336 0.14987080 0.28423773 0.281653747 0.16795866 0.036175711
               B   0.00000000 0.07075472 0.12735849 0.16981132 0.250000000 0.28301887 0.099056604
               Caa 0.00000000 0.01694915 0.03389831 0.10169492 0.237288136 0.35593220 0.254237288
```

The sub-sample:

```
                           Aaa         Aa          A        Baa         Ba          B         Caa
               Aaa 0.347826087 0.38043478 0.19565217 0.06521739 0.01086957 0.00000000 0.000000000
               Aa  0.068410463 0.49698189 0.23541247 0.12273642 0.05835010 0.01810865 0.000000000
               A   0.022336770 0.21477663 0.42268041 0.23883162 0.07903780 0.01718213 0.005154639
               Baa 0.004166667 0.10208333 0.29791667 0.31041667 0.19791667 0.07708333 0.010416667
               Ba  0.000000000 0.04234528 0.14332248 0.29315961 0.30618893 0.17915309 0.035830619
               B   0.000000000 0.04166667 0.08928571 0.19642857 0.25000000 0.31547619 0.107142857
               Caa 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.02272727 0.11363636 0.22727273 0.38636364 0.250000000
```

Standard errors for the sub-sample:

```
                           Aaa         Aa          A        Baa         Ba           B         Caa
               Aaa 0.049655673 0.05061622 0.04135903 0.02574205 0.01081033 0.000000000 0.000000000
               Aa  0.011323883 0.02242766 0.01903050 0.01471884 0.01051447 0.005981314 0.000000000
               A   0.006125525 0.01702271 0.02047636 0.01767359 0.01118348 0.005386585 0.002968352
               Baa 0.002940134 0.01381894 0.02087474 0.02111763 0.01818571 0.012174212 0.004634149
               Ba  0.000000000 0.01149312 0.01999846 0.02598026 0.02630548 0.021886386 0.010608027
               B   0.000000000 0.01541693 0.02200024 0.03065208 0.03340766 0.035852788 0.023862611
               Caa 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.02246752 0.04784519 0.06317721 0.073405285 0.065279121
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to divide by zero? There are many in the std errors dataset. Please post the exact formula you want to implement.

Comment: If they’re zero you’d omit the calculation for the element in the matrix.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do element-wise calculations.  That is, e.g.,  `(sub[1,1] - sample[1,1]) / se[1,1]` and then to do this for all elements in the matrices.  Because matrices are internally stored as vectors, and because basic math operators are vectorized, you should be able to just do `(sub - sample) / se`.

Comment: @DanY Thank you. Would my degrees of freedom be N-1?

Comment: My guess is yes - with the huge caveat that I did not carefully read the paper you link to.  Footnote 4 of that paper, however, suggests that this is a z-test and not a t-test, but the authors clearly state that they are performing t-tests.  My guess is that they are using a t-test as a conservative option and so mostly likely dof = n-1.

Comment: What is meant by sub-sample here? If that sub-sample matrix is calculated from the sample then you dependent data and a regular t-test is not suitable due to violations of independence. At the very least you need something like a paired t-test to account for the dependency, but the standard deviations of the sub sample are not sufficient for that - you need the standard deviation of the difference scores